# Line being occulted by surface plot with matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, surface

I am trying to plot a trajectory around the Earth and I am using plot_surface to plot the Earth and plot to add the trajectory to the same figure. The result looks like this:
[image: First View]

When I turn the figure to check a different perspective, I see this:
[image: Problem View]

One of the legs of the trajectory should be in front of the blue sphere and not behind (in particular, the lower leg in the above plot), but seems to send it to the back, even if the line is in the front in the coordinate space.

What do I do to plot it like it actually is in 3d space?

Thanks!

Comment: Matplotlib isn't really a 3d plotting library. It can do some basic plots in 3d but there are limitations. See this FAQ on the website - https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/toolkits/mplot3d/faq.html

Comment: As matplotlib doesn't do full 3D. The only thing you can do using matplotlib is first draw the circle with a small `zorder`, then the sphere, and lastly the part of the circle that is closest to the viewer (`zorder=3` or so). This will only work for certain eye positions. The `mayavi` library could be a replacement when full 3D is needed.

Answer (score 1):

in matplotlib, you can set the order of your plots with ***"zorder"***.

> The default drawing order for axes is patches, lines, text. This order is determined by the zorder attribute. The following defaults are set
>
> Artist                   Z-order Patch / PatchCollection  1 Line2D /
>   LineCollection    2 Text  3 You can change the order for individual
>   artists by setting the zorder. Any individual plot() call can set a
>   value for the zorder of that particular item.

The plot that you give `zorder =0` will lay under all of the plots and then zorder =1 on top of that and so on.
for example:

```
plt.plot(x, y, z, 'r-', zorder = 1)
```

for Axis3D you can also use zorder = -1.

Comment: Well, `zorder` won't help here, as OP needs the circle partial in front and partial behind the sphere.

Comment: @JohanC you are right but I thougt it is possible to assign two values to zorder for two episodes of the plot with "if".

Comment: thanks for the answer, but that would be too static a solution. I will try with mayavi, as @JohanC mentioned in his reply.

Comment: Yeah, his answer is better. I learned something from @JohanC too!